# Reading Text from Another Application's Frame

Tags: java, code-injection

I plan on creating a toy application to play games. Is it possible to capture game data from another applications frame? I know this is traditionally done using a low level language and using dll injection but i was wondering if this is possible to do from a high level language?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use sockets for IPC in a platform independent way.